# PHP imported data integrity

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, ms-access

I will try to explain situation as well as possible:

1. I have script, that imports CSV file data to MS Access database.
2. I have 2 access Tables:

A) Users and their information(ID, name, last name etc.)

B) Table which contains data from CSV file

Problem is, data imported from file, (2nd table) contains Users name and lastname. I want to get idea, how to, while reading csv file line by line, check what name line contains, and assign userID from table 1 instead of name and lastname on table 2. It should be done while importing, because, on each import there are roughly 3k lines being imported. Any ideas appreciated. Images given bellow.

**Import script:**

```
<?php
function qualityfunction() {
error_reporting(0); 
require_once '/Classes/PHPExcel.php'; // (this should include the autoloader)
require_once '/CLasses/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$excel_readers = array(
    'Excel5' , 
    'Excel2003XML' , 
    'Excel2007'
);
$files = glob('data files/quality/QA*.xls');
$sheetname= 'AvgScoreAgentComments';
if (count($files) >0 ) {
foreach($files as $flnam) {
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
$path = $flnam;
$excel = $reader->load($path);
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->save('data files/quality/temp.csv');

/*
$filename = basename($path);  
if (strpos($filename,'tes') !== false) {
echo 'true';
}*/
            require "connection.php";
            $handle = fopen("data files/quality/temp.csv", "r");
            try {
      $import= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO quality(
                              qayear,
                              qamonth,
                              lastname,
                              firstname,
                              score) VALUES(
                              ?,?,?,?,?)");
    $i = 0;        
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'")) !== FALSE) {
        if($i > 3) {
            $data = str_replace('",', '', $data); 
            $data = str_replace('"', '', $data); 
            $import->bindParam(1, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);             
            $import->bindParam(2, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(3, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $import->bindParam(4, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $import->bindParam(5, $data[7], PDO::PARAM_STR);            
            $import->execute();
        }
        $i++;
    }

    fclose($handle);
    $removal=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM quality WHERE score IS NULL;");
    $removal->execute();
            }
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";

}};
```

**Data table 1 (Users info):**

[image]

**Data table 2 (In which data from CSV file is imported)**

[image]

Comment: Yea, query the `user` table on `firstname` and `lastname` to get the `id` and use that id in your insert

Comment: And how to do that? That is my question.

Comment: Its just a F.L.O.C _Few lines of code_

Comment: Probably hundereds, but if you are asking for somone to _write it for you_ may I remind you **SO is not a free coding service** At least try to write it, if you then get problems ask another question with your attempts and we will then be more than willing to help. Alternatively, you will have to wait for a __points hound__ to do it for you.

Comment: No, I'm not asking to write code for me, I'm asking for proper example, that could help me to solve this issue. If you not willing to help, you are free to go and spam someone else :) In this place, I'm completely clueless, that is why I'm asking who could guide me correct way.

Comment: I told you how to do it in my first comment.

Comment: That is basically what I wrote in question. I know that that is the thing i need to do, but as I mentioned, I have no clue, how to do such thing. Databases clearly not my strongest part.

Comment: Thats what learning is all about. __Trial and error__ Have a stab at it

Comment: I know you are right, but I have you so much right now :D

Comment: bring in the data. then process it. After-the-fact patching so to speak. Until you are terribly fluent in all this stuff, don't try to get into the middle of the process like you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution. Thanks for help.**

```
$lastname = "lastname";
$firstname = "firstname";
$showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE lastname= :lastname AND firstname= :firstname");
$showdata->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$showdata->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$showdata->execute();
$rowas= $showdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $rowas['userID'];
```